# Trouble executing lsb-release in a Bitbucket Pipelines docker instance

Tags: python, bash, docker, lsb, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket Pipelines yaml that looks like this:

image: python:3.5.1

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install lsb-release -y
            - curl --silent https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
            - VERSION=node_5.x
            - DISTRO="$(lsb-release -s -c)"
            - echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
            - echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install nodejs -y
            - npm install
            - npm run build
            - python get-pip.py
            - pip install boto3==1.3.0
            - python s3_upload.py io-master.fromthiscomesthat.co.uk dist io-master
```

All working well, except `DISTRO="$(lsb-release -s -c)"` is failing. Cannot find the `lsb-release` executable, even though it's installed successfully in the script. I have tried `find / -name lsb-release` but that only yields the following:

```
+ find / -name lsb-release
/usr/share/doc/lsb-release
/usr/share/bug/lsb-release
```

...which is not very useful.

Where is the executable??

Answer (score 0):

`lsb-release` is the name of the package, `lsb_release` is the name of binary within.

How did I find out this:

1. Have docker installed on your host
2. Fetch docker image and run container in which to test `docker run -it --rm python:3.5.1 /bin/bash`
3. Install `lsb-release` with `apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release`
4. See files in package `dpkg -L lsb-release` (files in `**/bin` directories are executables)

Comment: Ok, I've done 1 to 3 already, but I'm having real problems installing the package. Is there a straightforward, idiot-proof means of installing the lsb-release binary??